# Publish web site in IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I want to publish my ASP.net based web page on Windows 7 machine.But,I got continually an error inside the below code.

```
<sessionState mode="Inproc" timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

Error Message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

<sessionState mode="Inproc" timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you configured your virtual directoy as an application and with the right .net framework (app pool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue lies in the error message:

```
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

Have you created an "Application" for it in IIS?  Does the website's node in IIS look like a folder or a globe?